# Remove Shopping Cart Item in Vue and Vuex Store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I'm trying to extend this awesome Repo https://github.com/vueschool/learn-vuex, i'm able to add products (via a db) to the cart successfully. Next i want to add a 'Remove Item' button to all items in the cart. I've tried the 'addtocart' logic by adding new mutators and actions but can't seem to get it to work.

ShoppingCart.vue

```
<template>
<div>
  <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="product in products">
      {{product.title}} - {{product.price | currency}} - 
   {{product.quantity}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Total: {{total | currency}}</p>
  <button @click="checkout">Checkout</button>
  <p v-if="checkoutStatus">{{checkoutStatus}}</p>
 </div>
</template>

 <script>
  import {mapState, mapGetters, mapActions} from 'vuex'
  export default {
  computed: {
  ...mapGetters('cart', {
    products: 'cartProducts',
    total: 'cartTotal'
  }),
  ...mapState('cart', {
    checkoutStatus: state => state.checkoutStatus
  })
  },
  methods: {
  ...mapActions('cart', ['checkout'])
  }
}
</script>
```

Cart.js

```
export default {
 namespaced: true,

state: {
 // {id, quantity}
 items: [],
 checkoutStatus: null
 },

 getters: {
  cartProducts (state, getters, rootState, rootGetters) {
   return state.items.map(cartItem => {
    const product = rootState.products.items.find(product 
       => product.id === cartItem.id)
     return {
      title: product.title,
      price: product.price,
      quantity: cartItem.quantity
    }
  })
 },

cartTotal (state, getters) {
  return getters.cartProducts.reduce((total, product) => 
 total + product.price * product.quantity, 0)
   },
 },

mutations: {
 pushProductToCart (state, productId) {
  state.items.push({
    id: productId,
    quantity: 1
   })
   },

 incrementItemQuantity (state, cartItem) {
  cartItem.quantity++
  },

 setCheckoutStatus (state, status) {
  state.checkoutStatus = status
 },

 emptyCart (state) {
  state.items = []
 }
 },

actions: {
addProductToCart({state, getters, commit, rootState, 
 rootGetters}, product) {
  if (rootGetters['products/productIsInStock'](product)) {
    const cartItem = state.items.find(item => item.id === 
  product.id)
    if (!cartItem) {
      commit('pushProductToCart', product.id)
    } else {
      commit('incrementItemQuantity', cartItem)
    }
    commit('products/decrementProductInventory', 
   product, {root: true})
  }
 },
 }
```

Comment: Fixed it.. Had to adjust the data going into the mutators for one particular product.